# Why do I have a "segmentation fault" in C but no memory leak in Python?

Tags: python, c, memory-leaks

I usually get memory leaks in C when I want to get an int from a user, but in Python, I can give a really large number and not get a null or segmentation fault or memory leak. Why is this?

Comment: Python has built-in support for large integers. Very convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Pythons integers don't have a size limit but instead increase until they use up your entire memory.